# complete a method that swaps the first and second half of an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays

I keep getting an out of bounds error whenever i try to run my code. Does anyone know what is wrong with it? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
public class Swapper{

    /**
    This method swaps the first and second half of the given array.
    @param values an array
     */

    public void swapFirstAndSecondHalf(int[] values) {
        // your work here

        int[] first = new int[values.length/2];
        int[] second = new int[values.length/2];
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length / 2; i++) {
            second[i] = values[i];
        }
        for (int j = values.length / 2; j < values.length; j++) {
            first[j] = values[j];
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < values.length / 2; k++) {
            values[k] = first[k];
        }
        for(int l = values.length / 2; l < values.length; l++) {
            values[l] = second[l];
        }
    }

    // This method is used to check your work
    public int[] check(int[] values) {
        swapFirstAndSecondHalf(values);
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input that causes the AIOOBE?

Comment: Try printing out the string representation of the array you modified in each for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] first = new int[values.length/2];
```

So indexes `[0..values.length/2 - 1]` are valid for `first`.

```
for (int j=values.length/2; j<values.length; j++)
{
    first[j] = values[j];
}
```

So with the first value of `j` being `values.length/2`, it's already out of bounds.

You need to practice debugging, placing a break point and tracing the code as it executes.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used `System.arraycopy()` instead of all the `for` looping.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    values = swapFirstAndSecondHalf(values);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));

    values = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    values = swapFirstAndSecondHalf(values);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}

public static int[] swapFirstAndSecondHalf(int[] values) {
    boolean evenSize = values.length % 2 == 0;
    int half = values.length / 2;
    int[] swapper = new int[values.length];
    System.arraycopy(values, evenSize ? half : half + 1, swapper, 0, half);
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, swapper, evenSize ? half : half + 1, half);

    // The middle number stays the middle number
    if (!evenSize) {
        swapper[half] = values[half];
    }
    return swapper;
}
```

Results:

```
[4, 5, 3, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

If you're wanting the middle number, for an odd sized array, to be part of the second half then the `swapFirstAndSecondHalf()` would look like this:

```
public static int[] swapFirstAndSecondHalf(int[] values) {
    boolean evenSize = values.length % 2 == 0;
    int half = values.length / 2;
    int[] swapper = new int[values.length];
    System.arraycopy(values, half, swapper, 0, evenSize ? half : half + 1);
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, swapper, evenSize ? half : half + 1, half);
    return swapper;
}
```

Results:

```
[4, 5, 3, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocating new arrays is a waste of space. Just swap the halves in-place:

```
public static void swapFirstAndSecondHalf(int[] values) {
    final int len = values.length / 2;
    final int offset = values.length - len;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int temp = values[i];
        values[i] = values[offset + i];
        values[offset + i] = temp;
    }
}
```

The code allows odd length, and will leave center value alone.